# How to properly add an ActionListeren to a custom JComponent

Tags: java, swing, listener, actionlistener, jcomponent

I often implement some panels, which provide common functionality like controls. For this I want to be able to add listeners, so that the caller can attach to the control and get notifications about changes.

So far I have simply used my own `List` where I keep the listeners and when I want to fire an action I loop through the list and call the listeners. From the outside this basically looks like any other `Swing` controls, however I was wondering if this is really the approach which should be used.

Especcially I was wondering if calling the listeners in a loop is what `Swing` itself also does, or if there is some kind of queue where you would put the actions, so that `Swing` decides when to deliver such actions.

When I investiaged this I came across this code:

```
protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
    ActionEvent e = null;

    // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
    // those that are interested in this event
    for (int i = listeners.length-2; i>=0; i-=2)
    {
        if(listeners[i] instanceof ActionListener)
        {
            // Lazily create the event:
            if (e == null)
            {
                String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();

                e = new ActionEvent(this,
                        ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                        actionCommand,
                        event.getWhen(),
                        event.getModifiers());
                e.setSource(event.getSource());
            }
            ((ActionListener)listeners[i+1]).actionPerformed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The member `listenerList` from `JComponent` is directly accessed, whcih feels a bit strange. However I didn't really find a better way so far. Also when adding a new listener to this, I do it now like shown below, but I'm not sure if this is really the appropriate way:

```
public void addQueryListener(ActionListener oListener)
{
    listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, oListener);
}

public void removeQueryListener(ActionListener oListener)
{
    listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, oListener);
}
```

So I would like to know, is accessing the `listenerList` member the correct way to add and remove listeners, so that they behave like any other standard control? Or is there some `best practice` how this should be done, which I'm missing so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping mind the restriction Swings put for Creating the gui. There is no harm accessing the 
** listenerlist ** this way. May be this is not best approach. 
Swing is Suppose to be Single Threaded and is not Thread Safe.

http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/GUI-Applications/Why-are-GUIs-Single-threaded/

AddListener and RemoveListener needed to be called on EDT(Event Dispatch Thread)
see See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread.

Also See for iteration of Listenere i.e when you call getActionListeners

its creates a copy of ListenersList and returns you back

Below Code from EventListenerList

```
public <T extends EventListener> T[] getListeners(Class<T> t) {
Object[] lList = listenerList; 
int n = getListenerCount(lList, t); 
    T[] result = (T[])Array.newInstance(t, n); 
int j = 0; 
for (int i = lList.length-2; i>=0; i-=2) {
    if (lList[i] == t) {
    result[j++] = (T)lList[i+1];
    }
}
return result;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a good example in the [`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) docs, and this [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) example uses its own `listenerList` in `ConverterRangeModel`.

Comment: I guess this is where I got my sample of firing an event from, as I didn't remember exactly where I found it. Well, it seems that accessing the listenerList is the way to go, even though it feels a bit strange to access a member directly. :)

Comment: I've seen it used in `JComponent` subclasses and also by itself like in `JFreeChart`.